# Integrate react routing into wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

i have a static frontpage in Wordpress with the url: "https://my-page.com/home".
I imported the .php file from my /theme/templates/home.php. Inside this file i imported the react script.

Now i have a problem with routing, in create-react-app it worked fine. My react script which i imported into my home.php looks like the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="" render={props => <div>Home</div>} />
          <Route path="/Blog" render={props => <div>Blog</div>} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Going to https://my-website.com/home prints me home, but going to  https://my-website.com/home/blog throws me an "404 website not found" error.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please make it if you only want to render `Blog` component:

```
<Route exact path="/home/blog" render={props => <div>Blog</div>} />
```

Let me know that's not your use case